# How to make chromedriver undetectable in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am coding some kind of "view booster" for NameMC. When you search a name, it adds one view to it. You can't add more than 1 view using a single IP. Yesterday I bought residential proxies, and it kinda works, but not how I want it to work. Sometimes it just doesn't add view, even after several refreshes (while using Chromedriver) but when I add the proxy server in Windows settings and open the website in my browser (not web driver) it works perfectly.

[image: Proxy server added in Windows settings]

Maybe NameMC somehow detects web driver? I have no idea how to fix this. I'm using Selenium.

Do you know any ways to make Chromedriver completely undetectable to websites?

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/